# Implementing oauth2 authentication on existing service

Tags: java, rest, playframework-2.0, oauth-2.0

I've got a rest service with three methods so not so complex. I used play framework and implemented some basic authentication (Global):

```
@Override
    public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {     
        if ("/dataDumps".equals(request.path()) || "/limitations".equals(request.path()) || "/entities".equals(request.path())) {
            if(null != request.getHeader("api-key") && request.getHeader("api-key").equals("xxxxxxx")) {
                return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
            } else {
                return new Action.Simple() {
                    @Override
                    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(play.mvc.Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
                        return F.Promise.pure((SimpleResult) forbidden());
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    }
```

Which works great. Now I got requirement that I need to add oauth2 authentication. Didn't do this before so surely I read some links like:

http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified
http://oauth.net/code/
http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2012/03/o-what-is-oauth-big-picture-free-ebook.html

I was trying to find example online of oauth service provider example implementation. I found this :

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example

But it's not even buildable with maven.

So I tried to see how it's done in this example and add the logic to my `onRequest` method, but in the example code request object is `HttpServletRequest` but my request object is `play.mvc.Http.Request`.

I found this gist https://gist.github.com/feliperazeek/1033587 which can solve this issue above but I feel like I'm overcomplicating stuff already before even getting started.

**1.** Spent fair amount of hours already reading and trying stuff out. Maybe someone who implemented Oauth service provider can give me some hints, helpful insight, links or code?

My service is going to be used by other clients which may be other services or devices so I assume I need to create authorization service so clients can authenticate against but at the same time they will be consuming my service.

**2.** Did I get it all wrong? Is there a better approach to do this what I described above (poorly probably)?